# MVC 5 Identity 2 - customer UserStore methods not being called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, identity, asp.net-identity-2

I am trying to implement a custom UserStore for my MVC 5 application so that I can delegate the database commands to my existing database project.

The tables in my database use integer keys, so I created a custom UserManager that inherits `UserManager<User, int>` instead of just `UserManager<User>`. For that reason, I also created a custom UserStore that implements `IUserPasswordStore<User, int>` instead of just `IUserPasswordStore<User>`.

Briefly:

```
public class CustomUserManager : UserManager<User, int>
{
    public CustomUserManager(CustomUserStore store) : base(store) 
    {
    }
}

public class CustomUserStore : IUserPasswordStore<User, int>
{
    private readonly DbContext _db;

    public CustomUserStore(DbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public Task<User> FindByIdAsync(int userId)
    {
        return _db.users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId);
    }

    public Task UpdateAsync(User user)
    {
        _db.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        return _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Now, it seems that when I call UpdateAsync on `CustomUserManager`, it does not go through my custom `CustomUserStore`, but rather through some default implementation or something. The problem is evident because `CustomUserManager.UpdateAsync()` returns `Task<IdentityResult>`, while my implementation in `CustomUserStore` returns just `Task`. Hence there are no errors or anything, but the method is not being called. I think `IUserPasswordStore<User, int>` should have some method `UpdateAsync` that returns `Task<IdentityResult>` but it doesn't...

On the other hand, the `FindByIdAsync` method does work fine and calls the method in my `CustomUserStore`.

I am quite sure the problem is due to inheriting the classes with the custom key type (int in my case). Any example of a custom UserStore I can find online just uses the string keys and does not inherit `IUserStore<User, int>` but just `IUserStore<User>`.

However I can't figure out my problem. Perhaps I can just override all the methods in my `CustomUserManager` but that seems like a work-around rather than a solution. Is this a bug in the framework perhaps, I think the custom key types is still relatively new or even in alpha?

Comment: Are you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question but I struggled yesterday with the same issue and after some time spent on it, I decided to take a look in the Identity source code and what I've found, almost made me smashed my head against the wall...

Simple, if you call `UserManager.UpdateAsync`, in the base class you will see that before the `UserStore.UpdateAsync` there is a validation that takes place, which, in my case, failed (doesn't matter the reason). So, please, be so kind and check in your class (controller class) the result of UpdateAsync which is an `IdentityResult` and more then sure the `Succes` result is false.

Evdin